# How does synaptic package manager work?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, intel, synaptic

I always wondered how the synaptic package work?
I always wanted to know it's secrets.
Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Synaptic** is a computer program which is a GTK+ graphical user interface front-end to the Advanced Packaging Tool for the Debian package management system. Synaptic is usually used on systems based on deb packages but can also be used on systems based on RPM packages. It can be used to install, remove and upgrade software packages and to add repositories.

### Features

- Install, remove, upgrade and downgrade single and multiple packages
- System-wide upgrade
- Package search utility
- Manage package repositories
- Find packages by name, description and several other attributes
- Select packages by status, section, name or a custom filter
- Sort packages by name, status, size or version
- Browse available online documentation related to a package
- Download the latest changelog of a package
- Lock packages to the current version
- Force the installation of a specific package version
- Undo/Redo of selections
- Built-in terminal emulator for the package manager

It also has the following features for Debian and Ubuntu only:

- Configure packages through the debconf system
- Xapian-based fast search
- Get screenshots from screenshots.debian.net

### Installation

**Synaptic** is no longer installed by default starting with Ubuntu 11.10.

You can install it by searching in the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/) for *synaptic* and clicking on *Synaptic Package Manager*.

Or, alternatively, open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal), and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

You can find more details about how to use it from [SynapticHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto#Getting_Started) or from [Website Developer](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/)

[image: Synaptic Package Manager]

Sources:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software)
- https://darryldias.me/2015/synaptic-on-ubuntu/